# Flex/Flash "popup balloon" control?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, components, widget

I'm looking for a Flash/Flex component which will create a "popup" editing balloon, similar to, for example, iCal or Google calendar:

http://img.skitch.com/20090526-phb5mke61anjkfknaekdbjjefw.jpg
[image]
<sub>(source: [iusethis.com](http://osx.iusethis.com/screenshot/osx/ical.png))</sub>

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Tooltip Control](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/ToolTip.html) is what you're looking for. You might want to extend the class to allow for more advanced functionality.

Comment: Hrm... That does sort of look like what I want... But it's also really ugly :P
I guess there's nothing prettier, though

Comment: You can customize it to look how you want.

Answer (score 1):

there are fallowing code for balloon popup. 
Atul Yadav
http://techy.limewebs.com

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="294" height="104" 
    backgroundAlpha="1.0" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF" borderColor="#1B86D1" 
    borderStyle="solid" creationComplete="DrowLine()">
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.core.Application;
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
        private function OnClose():void{
            PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
        }
        private function DrowLine():void{
                var pt:Point = new Point(0, -13);
                var global:Point = Application.application.localToGlobal(pt);
                var origin:Point =global;
                var destination:Point = new Point(150,0);
                var destination1:Point = new Point(50,0);
                var lineThickness:Number = 1;
                var lineColor:Number = 0x1B86D1;
                var lineAlpha:Number = 1;
                //Alert.show(global.toString());

                var tip:Canvas = new Canvas();

                tip.graphics.clear();
                tip.graphics.beginFill(0xffffff,1);

                tip.graphics.lineStyle(lineThickness,lineColor,lineAlpha);
                tip.graphics.moveTo(origin.x,origin.y);
                tip.graphics.lineTo(destination.x,destination.y);
                tip.graphics.lineStyle(1,0xffffff,lineAlpha);
                tip.graphics.lineTo(50,0);
                tip.graphics.lineStyle(1,0x1B86D1,1);
                tip.graphics.lineTo(origin.x,origin.y);
                tip.graphics.endFill();
                addChild(tip);

            }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
    <mx:TextArea x="10" y="25" width="274" id="txt_message" borderColor="#2487CC"/>
    <mx:Label x="10" y="75" text="Attach:" width="54" fontWeight="bold" color="#000000"/>
    <mx:Button x="58" y="73" label="Browse" cornerRadius="0" borderColor="#288ACF" color="#4DB111"/>
    <mx:Button x="219" y="73" label="Save" id="btn_save" name="btn_save" cornerRadius="0" color="#15AE11" borderColor="#308FD1"/>
    <mx:Image x="272" y="2" width="18" height="18" source="assets/Close.PNG" click="OnClose()"/>

</mx:Canvas>
```